# Get number of connections of determinated port

Tags: linux, numbers, port, connection, lsof

Looking for a linux function that returns the count of connections in a port.

Was researching about the "lsof", but it only prints connections in a door, and does not return the sum of all connections, for example: if I have two connections at port 80, it will return 2, and not the connections.

Comment: by 'does not return the connection' do you mean you need the 4-tuple for the connection ? Look at the sockstat utility. It shows per process connections with the 4-tuple. What do you mean 'prints connections in a door' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [netstat](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/netstat-command-tutorial-examples.html)?